# C# and SQLite; Optimal code for inserting into many-to-many relationship

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite

I am learning working with SQLite using C# and have a simple case. I want to retrieve information from WPF form and insert it into SQLite database. The structure is pretty simple I have one many-to-many relationship between article and author:
[Relationship picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLRGu.png)

And a simple form to enter the data:
[WPF form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSk3h.png)

What I want to achieve is to insert the new article from "Article Title" textbox and each author from "List view". The form listbox source is bound to ObservableCollection: 
`ObservableCollection<string> authorList = new ObservableCollection<string>();`

Using some basic guides on internet I wrote the following code, now the code works fine and does what I need it to do. But as I am still inexperienced I wonder if this way of doing things is a decent way. If not I would like some tips on what to change and how to improve the code.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string insertQuery;
    SQLiteCommand sqlCommand;

    //Variable to store last inserted article id and list for author ids
    long lastArtID;
    List<long> authorIDArray = new List<long>();

    //Query to insert new Article into tblArticle
    insertQuery = "INSERT INTO tblArticle (Title, PersonalComment, File) VALUES (@Name, @PersonalComment, @File)";
    sqlCommand = new SQLiteCommand(insertQuery, NikasDB.myConnection);
    NikasDB.OpenConnection();

    //Add parameters from the window_textboxes
    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txbTitle.Text);
    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PersonalComment", txbPersonalComment.Text);
    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@File", txbFileName.Text);
    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    //Retrieve newly added article id
    lastArtID = NikasDB.myConnection.LastInsertRowId;

    string selectQuery;
    SQLiteDataReader GetResult;

    //For each author in authorList check if author already exists
    //If it exists retrieve its id and store in authorIDArray
    //else first insert the author and then retrieve id
    foreach (var author in authorList)
    {
        selectQuery = "SELECT ID FROM tblAuthor WHERE Name=@Name";
        sqlCommand = new SQLiteCommand(selectQuery, NikasDB.myConnection);
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", author);
        GetResult = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
        if (GetResult.HasRows)
        {
            if (GetResult.Read())
            {
                authorIDArray.Add(GetResult.GetInt32(0));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            insertQuery = "INSERT INTO tblAuthor (Name) VALUES (@Name)";
            sqlCommand = new SQLiteCommand(insertQuery, NikasDB.myConnection);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", author);
            sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            authorIDArray.Add(NikasDB.myConnection.LastInsertRowId);
        }
    }

    //Foreach author Id insert ArticleID and AuthorID from list in joint table for many-to-many relationship
    foreach (var authorID in authorIDArray)
    {
        insertQuery = "INSERT into jntArticleAuthor (Article_ID, Author_ID) VALUES (@ArticleID, @AuthorID)";
        sqlCommand = new SQLiteCommand(insertQuery, NikasDB.myConnection);
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ArticleID", lastArtID);
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AuthorID", authorID);
        sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    NikasDB.CloseConnection();
    authorIDArray.Clear();
    authorList.Clear();
}
```

Comment: You should use a transaction as if the author insertion fails, you will stay with an article in your table, without related data... And suppose that you run the form again, and succeeds, you will get duplicated records in the tblArticle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here all the actions you are doing inside the button click event.

You can create a Data access layer for all DB related operations and inherit it in this class. So if you have another form then you can re use the same method
and separate insert select operations into different methods.